# How to add class if a product have Customizable Options in Product Details Page in magento 2

Tags: frontend, jquery, product-view, magento2.2.6

I have two types of products in my site
Type 1 :products with Customizable Options
Type 2 :products without Customizable Options

I wish to add one custom class(for css purpose) to the products which has Customizable Options, i mean I need a css class for Type 1 products. 
Please provide me a solution

Comment: Use `$isHasOptions = $product->getTypeInstance()->hasOptions($product);` to determine whether product has options or not

Comment: Okay, where the responding template of the customizable options are load in PDP page

Answer (score 1):

If Customizable_option is product attribute option than get value of this attribute and store in variable.

```
if($Customizable_option){ $class =  'Customizable_class';} <br>
if($without_Customizable_option)
{ 
  $class =  'without_Customizable_class';
  }
<br>
```

$class variable put in HTML element class

Answer (score 0):

In backend,while adding customizable options for the product then the magento adds the div class for the PDP page in frontend. 
The div class is product-options-wrapper .

So no need for customization